# Pass Parent Component ComponentDidMount data to Child ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well i'm new to react and i'm not clear how this componentDidMount functionality works practically.So i am performing an API call in componentDidMount of Parent Component. And
I want the API response data in child Component ComponentDidMount
Is there any way i can achieve this ? 
Please check the below code for further reference you may get clear idea after going through the code

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    businessMedia: null,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTopBusinessMedia()
  }

  getBusinessDetails = async () => {
    const { media, business } = this.state.businessMedia;

    let id = localStorage.getItem('id');
    const data = {
      url: 'home_page_counts/',
      body: {
        user_id: id,
        media_id: media[0].id,
        business_id:business[0].id,
      }
    }
    let businessDetails = await fetch_Login(data);
    if (businessDetails.status === 200) {
      this.setState({
        business: businessDetails.data.length > 0 ? businessDetails.data : []
      })
    }
  }

  getTopBusinessMedia = async () => {
    const data = {
      url: "topmedia_business/"
    }
    const topBusiness = await apiGet(data)

    if ('status' in topBusiness && topBusiness.status === 200) {
      const { business, media } = topBusiness
      console.log("Business Media Data ",topBusiness)
      this.setState({ businessMedia:topBusiness }, () => {
        this.getBusinessDetails()
      })
    } else {
      consol.log("failed")
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { business, media,businessMedia } = this.state;

    return (
            <Child businessMedia={businessMedia}/>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
  console.log("Props Vlaue >>>",this.props)
  //in this component i want parent component API call data
  }

   render() {
    const { business, media,businessMedia } = this.state;

    return (
            <NewsFeeds businessMedia={businessMedia}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the state (this.setState) from componentDidMount.

Example with class and componentDidMount -> [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-paper-1q7n0?file=/src/App.js)
Example with functions and hooks -> [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-cache-qp0fi?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually receiving data from parent, so `this.state` in children should be `this.props`

```
getBusinessDetails = async () => {
    const { media, business } = this.state.businessMedia;

    let id = localStorage.getItem('id');
    const data = {
      url: 'home_page_counts/',
      body: {
        user_id: id,
        media_id: media[0].id,
        business_id:business[0].id,
      }
    }
    let businessDetails = await fetch_Login(data);
    if (businessDetails.status === 200) {
      //check whether this block of code printed on the console.
      console.log('does it run????')
      this.setState({
        business: businessDetails.data.length > 0 ? businessDetails.data : []
      })
    }
  }
```

```
class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
  console.log("Props Vlaue >>>",this.props)
  //in this component i want parent component API call data
  }

   render() {
    // your businessMedia data is from parent, use this.props to grab it 
    const { businessMedia } = this.props;
    const { business, media } = this.state;

    return (
       <NewsFeeds businessMedia={businessMedia}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: i want the parent component API data in ComponentDidMount of Child.
here the console log for props is having empty data